# Laravel 5.1 Redirect With Get Variables

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am trying to figure out this redirect in Laravel 5.1 but I am getting the error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

This is the redirect I'm trying to achieve

```
http://example.com/tool/view.php?username=asdf

to

http://example.com/asdf
```

This is my current routes file

```
Route::get('/tool/view.php?username={username}', 'MainController@redirect');

Route::get('/{username}', 'MainController@profile');
```

and this is my current controller file

```
public function redirect($username) {
    return Redirect::to('/' . $username, 301);
}

public function profile($username) {
    return view('profile', ['username' => $username]);
}
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify... my redirect() function is never getting called because the url http://example.com/tool/view.php?username=asdf isn't being assigned to a route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redirect to a route that doesn't exists.At the end of your routfile add something like this:    `Route:get('{username}', 'YourController@method');`

Update

```
Route::get('/tool/view.php', function() {
    return Redirect::to(Input::get('username'), 301);
```

}

Comment: That didn't work. I already have a route for http://example.com/asdf (Route::get('/{username}', 'MainController@profile');) What I need is a route that redirects http://example.com/tool/view.php?username=asdf to http://example.com/asdf I went ahead and edited the question to include my other route and function

Comment: Have you printed out the username in your redirect function? And what happens if you call example/asdf directly ?

Comment: It works perfectly when I go to http://example.com/asdf. Username gets passed etc. I just have a bunch of /tool/view.php?username=blah urls indexed in google and want to redirect them to the new version aka http://example.com/blah

Comment: And it's not possible to directly go to the short URL? So you don't the the view.php call?

Comment: I can directly visit the short version and it works. I want to also redirect the long version to the short version for SEO purposes

Comment: I think the problem is the get variable. Change your route to `view.php` and for the username set `Request::get('username');`